# How to make p-dropdown placeholder go up?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, p-dropdown

I've p-dropdown, and i need to make its placeholder to going up, when i choose one of the sort options, like on screenshots. Is there any way to achieve it with p-dropdow? Cause when i just add  `placeholder="Sort by"` to p-dropdown, it disappears, when i choose sort options

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with raw html and css as follows. You might be able to adapt it to suit your needs.

```css
.input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.input-container>label {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0.5rem;
  top: -0.4rem;
  padding-inline: 0.25rem;
}

.input-container:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #0000ff;
}

.input-container:focus-within>label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-container:focus-within input::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.input-container>input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=input-container><label id='placeholder-text' for='cats'>Choose a cat</label>
  <input id='cats' placeholder='Choose a cat' type="text" list="catoptions" />
  <datalist id="catoptions">
    <option>Tiger</option>
    <option>Lion</option>
    <option>Jaguar</option>
    <option>Kitten</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```